# Are there any harm to keep detaching thread in C++ 11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, timer

Often in my program I need to launch a task in 10 milliseconds without blocking the current thread. What is the best tool and framework to do this? I did some research on boost async but I am not sure if boost is too slow. I am using C++11 thread. According the standard when a detached thread finishes execution the OS will reclaim the resource. I come up with the following code:
Are there better (more efficient) ways to do this?　are there any problem with my pseudo code?

```
void delayed_task(){

          std::this_thread::sleep_for(10)
          work_on_delayed_task();

}


int main()
{

    while(true){

           std::thread my_thread(delayed_task);
           my_thread.detach();
           do_main_work();

         }

}
```

Comment: Why not simply joining the thread after `do_main_work();`? Detaching is a bad idea in most cases.

Comment: @PasserBy exactly my point http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html

Comment: @PasserBy It does on windows, but is called `Sleep()` then.

Comment: My true concern is that the program will keep creating delayed task and detach them. Are there any limit on the number of times I can create new threads? Will the application runs slower as time passes ?  Is LINUX signal, timer a better tool for this?

Comment: The threads will terminate after returning

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Calling join will block current thread and wait for another thread to finish. I want my main thread keeps working

Comment: @PasserBy So we both agree that when the function return ,the detached threads will terminate. My concern is whether there is any harm creating too many detached threads,(they don't need to run simultaneously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::async` is a thing now, and don't worry about its performance until you actually observe a problem

```
#include<future>
#include<chrono>
#include<utility>

using namespace std::literals;

template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
auto delay(std::chrono::milliseconds ms, Fn fn, Args&&... args)
{
    return std::bind([ms, fn](Args&&... args) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(ms);
        return fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void some_work() {}

int main()
{
    auto f = std::async(delay(10ms, some_work));
    f.get();
}
```

Comment: Although you mentioned not to worry about performance, in fact I am doing time critical jobs (trading) when milliseconds count. How efficient is std:: async, does a G++ compiler  use a thread to implement async i guess?  Is LINUX signal, timer a better tool?

Comment: @YufeiZheng I would argue you should still, measure before optimizing. If this accounts for 1% of your performance, why bother at first? Unless you are certain that the performance here is the easiest to improve on, it really isn't worth it

Comment: @YufeiZheng And if you are really sensitive to time, no reasonably-sized answer will be satisfying. I suggest you first look into threadpools if creating threads is a holdup, and then look into options of inter-thread synchronization, as that would be something too.

Comment: Thanks for you advice. I see many ways to accomplish this type of job. (detach a thread, std::async,  boost asio library) Could you comment more on these ? Which one is the most efficient? I am using 64 bit LINUX with G++ compiler

Comment: @YufeiZheng I am no expert, and the decision should be made, again by measuring.